# Splitting String in List but keeping the delimiter

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a list of strings:

```
List = ['aaa', 'bbb ccc', 'ddd (eee)']
```

I want to split elements that have parantheses either at the blank before the "(" or at the "(" in case that there is no blank ahead. But in this case, I want to keep the parantheses. So far I have come up with the following code that works if there is a blank:

```
for l in List:
   if re.search('\(', l) != None:
       a,b = re.split(' (?=\()', l)
       print('True')
       List_2.append(a)
       List_2.append(b)
   else:
       List_2.append(l)

print(List_2)
```

Two Questions: First, is there a cleaner version of this, maybe using list comprehension.
Second, how do I capture a case without a blank 'fff(ggg)'.

The final list should then look like this:

```
List_correct['aaa', 'bbb ccc', 'ddd', '(eee)', 'fff', '(ggg)']
```

Comment: By the way, use `is not None` istead of `!= None`.

Comment: Why are there more elements in your result then in your source? Where do `'fff'` and `'(ggg)'` come from? Where is the example when the () should be removed?

Comment: Why `'bbb ccc'` becomes `'bbb', 'ccc'` in the second question?

Comment: And you should use `r'\('` instead of `'\('`

Comment: `[x for l in List for x in re.split(r'\s*(?=\()', l) if x]`, see https://ideone.com/WaNUoC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Code:**

```
List = ['aaa', 'bbb ccc', 'ddd (eee)', 'fff(ggg)']
result = [subitem for item in List for subitem in re.split(r"(?:\b|\s)(?=\()", item)]
```

**Output:**

```
>>>print(result)
['aaa', 'bbb ccc', 'ddd', '(eee)', 'fff', '(ggg)']
```

Comment: Nice answer! You can improve the regex as `\s|\b(?=\()` which takes 24 steps whereas your regex takes 62 steps. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Si6Sh7/1)

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thanks for your suggestion i will improve the answer.

Comment: My apologies! Your regex meets the requirement precisely. I missed the requirement that `bbb ccc` should remain together. Also, my regex, `\s|\b(?=\()` will fail for  whitespace inside parentheses (however, there is no such requirement mentioned in the question). I can think of an alternative regex,  `\b(?=\()|\s(?![^(])` [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pYXNmM/1) | [Demo using Java](https://ideone.com/fM6LBu); but you do not need to change your solution.